# Selecting key name of parent objects when child object contains a specific key

Tags: json, jq

Given the following JSON containing 3 variables:

```json
{
  "variables": {
    "AWS_ROLE": "DevOpsAccessRole",
    "AWS_REGION": {
      "description": "AWS region",
      "value": "us-west-2",
      "options": [
        "us-west-2",
        "us-east-1"
      ]
    },
    "ENVIRONMENT": {
      "description": "Environment to deploy to",
      "value": "dev",
      "options": [
        "dev",
        "qa",
        "prod"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My goal is to select only the variable names containing the `description` field.

So the desired output is (don't care about the order):

```json
AWS_REGION
ENVIRONMENT
```

`AWS_ROLE` should be left out since it does not contain the `description` key.

I've initially tried:

`jq -r '.variables | keys []'`

Which returns:

```
AWS_ROLE
AWS_REGION
ENVIRONMENT
```

But I'm stuck removing the ones without `description`.

Also tried:

`jq -r '.variables |..| select(.description?)'`

but the problem here is that I loose access to the variable names.

How can I do this in `jq` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `to_entries` to get simultaneous access to both the `.key` and the `.value`, test the existence of a (sub-)key using `has`, and use `?` to suppress errors if it is not an object (thus has no key, and would error out). Using the `-r` flag gives you a raw-text output.

```bash
jq -r '.variables | to_entries[] | select(.value | has("description")?).key'
```

```
AWS_REGION
ENVIRONMENT
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/NyCo9uirTSt)

---

The same technique using `keys`, iterated over and stored in a variable:

```bash
jq -r '.variables | keys[] as $k | .[$k] | select(has("description")?) | $k'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/OwLkpEgTJWf)

Comment: Inspired by your answer, this one would also work since the description will only be present inside objects:  *jq -r '.variables | to_entries[] | select(.value | objects).key'*

Comment: @donhector It depends on your precise constraints. `select(.value | objects)` would also match items that are objects but do not contain a field named `description`. If that also fits your needs, sure, go for it. For that matter, you could also first eliminate all non-objects, then extract all keys: `.variables | .[] |= objects | keys[]`.